# Run the script in new thread when file is created using watchdog

Tags: python, multithreading, watchdog

I want to run function in a new thread whenever a file is created in the folder which watchdog is monitoring.
Currently I use watchdog to monitor the folder and call the function when a file is created.

```
import sys
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler
from sys import platform
from script import scanning as scp
def main():
  patterns =['*.txt']
  my_event_handler = PatternMatchingEventHandler(patterns, None, False, True)
  def on_created1(event):
     directory = event.src_path
     scp.gettingfile(directory)
  my_event_handler.on_created = on_created1
  path = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) >1 else "."
  go_recursively = True
  my_observer = Observer()
  my_observer.schedule(my_event_handler, path, recursive=go_recursively)
  my_observer.start()
  try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
        my_observer.stop()
        my_observer.join()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I would like to run the script `scp.gettingfile(directory)` in a thread when file is created and watchdog will continue monitoring the folder to create another thread whenever a new file is created.

After executing scp.gettingfile(directory), the corresponding thread will be closed.
May I know how can I create a thread in watchdog?

Comment: do you want the watchdog to continue only after the "thread" is completed? in that case you don't actually need to run it in a separate thread

Comment: No Dash. For example when file1 is created, watchdog triggered the ```spc.gettingfile(directory)``` in a new thread and execute the script. When file2 is created before finish executing file1 in the thread1, watchdog will create new thread  for file2 and execute ```spc.gettingfile(directory)```. So there will be 2 threads running and when the first thread is finished, the thread1 will close.

Comment: which version of python are you using? it can be done several different ways depending on which version/sub version

Comment: I am using python 3.6.2

Answer (score 0):

you can use the built in threading library to execute the function directly, or write your own function that wraps, for example

```
import threading
t = threading.Thread(target=scp.gettingfile, args=(directory))
t.daemon = True
t.start()
```

edit:
here are the docs: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/threading.html

Comment: Thank you.
May I know I need to add threading inside the on_created1(event)?
```
import threading
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler
from script import scanning as scp
def main():
  patterns =['*.txt']
  my_event_handler = PatternMatchingEventHandler(patterns, None, False, True)
  def on_created1(event):
     directory = event.src_path
     t = threading.Thread(target = scp.gettingfile,args=(directory))
     t.daemon = True
     t.start()
  my_event_handler.on_created = on_created1

```